# Subdomain redirect to a full URL and keeping original subdomain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

So, to be more graphic at the beginning:

This is current link structure:

`http://example.com/video-slug/wordpress-title-of-the-video-slug`

I have a subdomain:

`http://tv.example.com/`

What I want to achieve is, when someone clicks on:

`http://tv.example.com/wordpress-title-of-the-video-slug`

It figures out that `tv.example.com` equals `example.com/video` and opens the the link:

`http://example.com/video/wordpress-title-of-the-video-slug`, but keeps the structure in location bar:

`http://tv.example.com/wordpress-title-of-the-video-slug`

Comment: htaccess is the way to go!

Comment: You want a rewrite, not a redirect.

Comment: I appreciate stating the obvious, I've tagged .htaccess here so people would assume that I know which way to go, BUT I need coding help, since my .htaccess knowledge is equal to 1 degree on Kelvin scale.

Comment: Do you have `tv.example.com` pointed to `example.com` already?

Comment: I do, but then I get tv.example.com/video/title instead tv.example.com/title...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a rewrite rule in your `.htaccess` file.  From memory, something like this should work.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/video/$1 [NC]
```

Placed in the `tv` subdomain.

Comment: It sends everything to `example.com/video` so `tv.example.com/video-title-slug` goes same as `tv.example.com`

Comment: Great, it redirects now, now is there a way to keep it in location bar as is; now when I type `tv.example.com/video-title` it opens `example.com/video/video-title`, but also changes it in location bar, any way to force it to stay `tv.example.com/video-title`?

Comment: I don't think that's possible as you're pointing to a different subdomain.

Answer (score 2):

A more generic solution, that applies to your question.
It allows any http://subdomain.example.com/ to serve the content located at http://example.com/subdomain/ while keeping the original URL (with subdomain).

The P option (for Proxy) serves that purpose (to keep the original URL in the address bar), and answers the question asked in accepted answer comments (i can't comment back tho..)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1/$1 [L,P]
```

for your specific case it would be

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tv\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/video/$1 [L,P]
```

A drawback i am facing now is that PHP $_SERVER URI is set to the translated URL not the original one. But that is another issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an easier way using PHP:

```
<?php 
//add some params
$_GET['param1'] = value1;
//the actual page you wish to redirect to
include "/var/www/page.php";

?>
```